Is it possible to get an icon of a file in electron?
I can't seem to figure out how to get an icon of a file from it's path.
I have tried using app.getFileIcon(), but this function returns an icon resembling the files extension type. Also have tried nativeImage.createThumbnailFromPath() but it gives me this error "Error: Failed to get thumbnail from local thumbnail cache reference".
Is it even possible?

What is "the icon of a file" if it's not the icon representing the file type?

So the difference is, an icon representing the file type is for exmaple: a text file would have an icon of a pen because it's a .txt file (for example) but the actual icon of the text file would be a note paper, and the note paper is exactly what i need

I don't get this distinction. Usually all text files have the same icon, regardless where they show up, and this icon will be chosen by the OS to represent the file type. Are you maybe confusing thumbnails (with actual content) the filebrowser of your OS (e.g. Nautilus of GNOME, Dolphin of KDE, Windows Explorer or the Mac Finder) is generating with the icon of the file? The latter is probably impossible to get, because these probably aren't persisted by the application generating them like the ones of images files (which are typically much larger) would be.

Yes thumbnial, that's the correct word, that's what i'm trying to get, i have achieved this using a powershell script but the image comes out very blurry and low quality
